# How to properly import .csv file into Tableau?

Tags: csv, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I've exported a dataframe from R into a .csv file and then tried to open it in Tableau. What is the correct way to import these files? I've done connect to data source > to a file > text file then simply clicked on the csv.

However, the columns and rows are all mixed up and I'm not sure what's gone wrong as the files can open in Numbers and Excel just fine!

Please see the incorrectly imported data rem_posts.csv and correctly imported data kylie_posts.csv.

[image]

[image: kylie_posts.csv]

Comment: Have you checked the raw CSVs outside Tableau to check they are well-formed? If, for example, the actual field content has commas in the text, the whole field needs to be enclosed in quotes (like "thing1, thing2" otherwise the commas will be parsed by Tableau as a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an issue with some columns having string data with commas in it so it was messing up the import when using csv format. I resolved this by exporting it in excel instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Data Interpreter](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/data_interpreter.htm)

Yo may also try using Tableu Prep , to do some cleanup